# How to extend Button component and allow space event

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to create a custom component. By default it will be collapsed and show only a button (therefore, I want to extend Button and not any other component!). When a user clicks on this button, it will expand and show some fields inside it. The problem I face now (which looks like a bug), is that it is impossible to type space character inside those fields. I minimized my code just to several lines:

```
    Ext.define('Ext.ux.CustomMenu', {
        extend: 'Ext.button.Button',
        alias: 'widget.custommenu',
        requires: [
            'Ext.XTemplate'
        ],
        autoEl: {},
        baseCls: Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'test-btn',
        renderTpl: '<div class="foo"></div>',
        afterRender: function() {
            this.callParent();
            this.attachField();
        },
        attachField: function () {
            Ext.create("Ext.form.field.Text",{
                renderTo: this.el.query('.foo')[0]
            });
        }
    });

    Ext.create("Ext.ux.CustomMenu",{
        renderTo: document.getElementById("button")
    });
```

And here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/21ei), which shows this strange behaviour. So, how can I fix it? And please pay attention, that I really need to extend Button component.

Comment: "I really need to extend Button component." You probably don't. Just describe the problem, not what you have already decided the solution is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ext.button.Button` catches per default all `SPACE` and `ENTER` keydown events and stops them. So, your input field don’t get these.
You need to override this part of `Ext.button.Button`.

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.CustomMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.button.Button',
    ([...]

    onEnterKey: function (e) {
        if(e.type === 'keydown' && e.getKey() == e.SPACE)
        {
            return;
        }

        return this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Here is the full example:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/21em